# Ctypes with multiprocessing, impossible to keep and update it ! How to update without reset?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, ctypes

i have a little question, i use like this code for my parsing project, of course is multiprocessing, so for each website use 1 different process right ?

OK, now if u want write on top console cmd like me screen https://i.ibb.co/whfsjXG/cmdd.png

```
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f'ALL SITE: {num_listko}  |  SITE VALID: {num_listok}  |  REMAIN: {remain_scan}')
```

For each site, that will be reset... :( but i need to keep and update it each time, no reset.

Anyone can tell me how to do it ?
**Thanks**

```
.........other moduls

import multiprocessing
import os
import time
import ctypes

NUM_PROCESSES = 20

def worker_main(queue):
    while True:
        item_site = queue.get(block=True) #block=True means make a blocking call to wait for items in queue
        if item_site is None:
            break

        do_work(item_site)


def main():
    global litst_to_scan
    the_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    the_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(NUM_PROCESSES, worker_main,(the_queue,))
            
    for item_site in list_site_pars:
        the_queue.put(item_site)
    
    for i in range(NUM_PROCESSES):
        the_queue.put(None)

    # prevent adding anything more to the queue and wait for queue to empty
    the_queue.close()
    the_queue.join_thread()

    # prevent adding anything more to the process pool and wait for all processes to finish
    the_pool.close()
    the_pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example isuse error:

```
try:
    resp = requests.head(site, timeout=3, stream=True, verify=False, allow_redirects=True).url
    remain_scan -= 1
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f'ALL SITE: {num_listko}  |  SITE VALID: {num_listok}  |  REMAIN: {remain_scan}  |  REMAIN: {total_finish_global}')



    if "LORE_IPSIUM" in response.text:
        total_finish_global += 1
        print("URL FOUND")
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f'ALL SITE: {num_listko}  |  SITE VALID: {num_listok}  |  REMAIN: {remain_scan}  |  REMAIN: {total_finish_global}')
```

Comment: It's not clear what are the desired and actual behaviors.

Comment: I have update the question, also if you see now "Example isuse error:" i count how many site remain to scan, how many site is done.

Every this info i print on TOP of console "wintitle" cmd if u see the picture (maybe u can understan), but when the python start scan a new site all info reset.

Comment: Is there an actual error (traceback)? Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is still not clear. How does the second code relate to the first? Provide one code that illustrates the problem

Comment: I have make just 30 second screencast, https://myvideopython.b-cdn.net/videopy.mp4 i same code but the second down use threads but the first one use multiprocessing.